# L'Hospital rule on discretized PDEs

Tags: limits, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Somehow I cannot wrap my head around following problem: A diffusion PDE is discretized in time and in space. To apply the boundary conditions I have seen, that in literature, they apply the rule of l'Hospital to avoid the singularity that exists at $\chi=0$.

The PDE is in spherical coordinates 1D, spatial coordinates are normalized at the current particle radius $\chi = \frac{r}{r_p(t)}$ and the symmetry BC is applied at r=0.

$\partial_t T = \frac{\alpha}{r_p^2} \partial_{\chi \chi}T + \frac{2 \alpha}{\chi r_p^2} \partial_\chi T+ \frac{\chi}{2 r_p^2} \dot{r_p} \partial_\chi T$

with the symmetry boundary condition

$\partial_\chi T\rvert_{\chi=0} = 0$

The discretized version of this looks like this with Crank-Nicolson:

$T_{i-1}^{n+1} (-A+B+C) + T_{i}^{n+1} (1+2A) + T_{i+1}^{n+1} (-A-B-C) = T_{i-1}^{n} (A-B-C) + T_{i}^{n} (1-2A) + T_{i+1}^{n} (A+B+C)$

with $A = \frac{\alpha \Delta t}{r_p^2 \Delta \chi^2}; B = \frac{\alpha \Delta t}{\chi_i r_p^2 \delta \chi} ; C = \frac{\chi_i \Delta t}{4 r_p^2 \Delta \chi} \dot{r_p}$

when I now apply l'Hospitals rule on the PDE the last term vanishes, since $\chi$ is in the numerator, but applying the rule at the second term, I end up with $\frac{3\alpha}{r_p^2} \partial_{\chi \chi}T $ since the second term leads me to $lim_{\chi \rightarrow 0} \frac{2\alpha}{r_p^2} \partial_{\chi \chi} T$ which leads me to unexpected behaviour and the discretized version of the PDE at $\chi = 0$ is not the same like in the literature no matter what spatial discretization scheme I use.

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you all in advance!